# Printing bit patterns

Tags: java

So I am to be making a "bit pattern that will have 7 rows. I am having trouble drawing any letters with 1's and 0's while I can only use `if` or `else` statements, `parse.Int`, and `compareTo` as the instructions say. The program needs to change every 1 to an "X" and every 0 to a space. Is there a specific way to do this? For now it just endlessly loops. Thanks for any and all help. Here is my code thus far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String r1 = ("1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r2 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r3 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r4 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r5 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r6 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0");
    String r7 = ("0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0");

    dr(r1);
    dr(r2);
    dr(r3);
    dr(r4);
    dr(r5);
    dr(r6);
    dr(r7);
}
public static void dr(String s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 1)
    {
    String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
    if (tokens[0].compareTo("0") == 0)
        System.out.println("X");
    else if (tokens[1].compareTo("1") == 1)
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need any special libraries for printing 0's and 1's??

Comment: @CrakC I dont need special libraries for that. I am to be creating a bit pattern that basically draws whatever letters I put with 1's and 0's.

Comment: Is the amount of columns fixed at 19?

Comment: The rows will be locked at 7. But no the columns are not locked. They are only "locked" by whatever letter I may type in.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it in your case is something like this:

```
String data = "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0";
String out = data.replaceAll("1,? ?","X").replaceAll("0,? ?", " "));
```

Comment: That is certainly an awesome way! But I am unable to use any specialized library.

Comment: Specialized? `replaceAll` is part of `String` class with no additional libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. What I was meaning is we are not allowed to use elements we have not gone over. He has yet to go over those elements, thus why I am in a predicament. The compare to and if/else statements are the only way we can do this program. It is unfortunate, but such as the way of things.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you assign each letter a value (Your bits), and then  storing them in an array...

We need the code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I would post the code, but so far all I have is the array set and a method to pass a function through. But the problem I am fighting with is actually drawing with 1's and 0's as the logic has to be set. So no matter what letters I put in, it needs to draw at least 3 letters.

Comment: atleast 3 letters? why so??